# Can't get RDFlib to work on windows

Tags: rdflib

I have installed RDFlib 3.0 and everything that is needed, but when I run the following code I get an error. The code below is from: http://code.google.com/p/rdflib/wiki/IntroSparql. I have tried for hours to fix this but with no success. Can please someone help?

```
import rdflib
rdflib.plugin.register('sparql', rdflib.query.Processor,
                       'rdfextras.sparql.processor', 'Processor')
rdflib.plugin.register('sparql', rdflib.query.Result,
                       'rdfextras.sparql.query', 'SPARQLQueryResult')

from rdflib import ConjunctiveGraph
g = ConjunctiveGraph()
g.parse("http://bigasterisk.com/foaf.rdf")
g.parse("http://www.w3.org/People/Berners-Lee/card.rdf")

from rdflib import Namespace
FOAF = Namespace("http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/")
g.parse("http://danbri.livejournal.com/data/foaf")
[g.add((s, FOAF['name'], n)) for s,_,n in g.triples((None, FOAF['member_name'], None))]

for row in g.query(
        """SELECT ?aname ?bname
           WHERE {
              ?a foaf:knows ?b .
              ?a foaf:name ?aname .
              ?b foaf:name ?bname .
           }""",
        initNs=dict(foaf=Namespace("http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"))):
    print "%s knows %s" % row
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 18 in <module>
    initNs=dict(foaf=Namespace("http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"))):
TypeError: query() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initNS'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally found the answer. You can read it here:
http://blog.eddsn.com/2010/05/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/

Comment: You should actually copy/paste the answer here in case your blog ever goes down.

Answer (score 2):

> In the meantime I found a workaround
>   which is to install minGW32 and
>   compile it with  that.  So for anyone
>   with a similar problem:
>
> 1. Download minGW32 installer from sourceforge
> 2. When you install the tool and get the screen asking what components to
>      install,  select "MinGW base tools",
>      "g++ compiler" and "MingW make".
> 3. After MinGW is installed, add C:\MinGW\bin to your Path environment
>      variable

from http://code.google.com/p/rdflib/issues/detail?id=104#c4